# How to get version of program in Vala?

Tags: version, vala

I'm starting to learn Vala and after just a few lines of code, I just encountered my first problem. It should be kinda easy but somehow I can't find anything on Google ('vala version number' or 'vala get version number' or 'how to get version of program in vala' don't bring up anything useful).

The online documentation of Vala doesn't bring up anything useful, either. Throughout the web I find stuff on how to get Vala's version or GTK version or stuff like that.

*edited stuff*

What I want to get: The version of the program that is running. It should query itself to get it's own version number. I can set a version number for the project in the Anjuta IDE so I expect to be able to get that version information somehow. Since I *can* get the name of the application (via GLib.Environment) I **should** be able to get the version information, too.

*edit end*

May someone please be so kind and help me out here? It seems my GoogleFu isn't with me today.

Comment: You aren't very clear on the version of what you want to get. The version of the Vala compiler? Or whatelse?

Comment: @lethalman the version of the program itself. I'm using the Anjuta IDE and in there, I can set a version number for a project. I should somehow be able to query that version number from the program itself. The same I can do `GLib.Environment.get_application_name().to_string()` to get the application's name, I should be able to get the version number. But somehow there is no `GLib.Environment.get_version()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the autotools, the generated config.h header will contain your package version. The symbols can then be used from Vala via a custom config.vapi binding. You could check out [sampala](https://github.com/tadeboro/Sampala/), it shows the trick.

Comment: wasn't the way I hoped for but thanks :). Hoped for something like you do in C#: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`. I guess your answer means that there is nothing alike.

Comment: well, I guess I need some more assistance: I see the `Intl` stuff which I guess is neccessary for this but I fail to see where stuff get's read/written to a file. And again, Google doesn't give anything helpful here. Even the Vala documentation has nothing to say about these functions from `Intl`.